# How to detect a usb drive in Java

Tags: java, file-io, usb

I would like to know how to detect a usb drive. I have already read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831825/detect-usb-drive-in-java/%22this%20post%22) but I am interested in knowing if we can just use `java.io.*;` to check for the usb drive. The post that i have read up, does kind of explain how to use `java.io.*;` but I didn't quite understand. If someone could provide an example, that would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could you the File.listRoots() Method.

There is a Post about that: [Post on Stackoverflow on File.listRoots()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980509/enumerate-external-drives)

The problem here is that you would need a name or some other info to identify the drive as a USB-Drive. Else you can't tell normal drives and usb-drives appart with this method.

Answer (score 0):

This works at least on Linux

```
File f = new File("/media");
for(File fls : f.listFiles()){
    System.out.print(fls+"\n");
}
```

Remember external plugged device storage on Linux can be found on **/media**