# can we detect the unique serial no of USB Pen Drive in java?

Tags: java, usb-drive

I have googled a lot but there are few examples to find the serial no of usb drive using c++. I want to find out the the unique id of usb flash drive in java? Or any other id such that I can identify USB Flash Drive uniquely.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547762/how-to-detect-a-usb-drive-in-java

Comment: Hello Abi: did read my question properly? According to your referred link I can get only the Drive Alphabet, Name, writable or readable but not getting any USB pen drive unique identifier!

Comment: If you can't find anything, you can resort to a native method.

Comment: @Banshidhari Not putting this as an answer, as I have never used it, but I have been doing some rooting around on google for you, and this looks promising.
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/j-usb/index.html